# Use EF to select object and its properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working in EF 4.3.1 and everything is going pretty well on the Insert side. But now I am trying to pull the objects I inserted back out to show in a View in my MVC3 project and having problems.

In my DAL, I have the following method to get a `Church` object from the database:

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
{
    return _db.Find(id);
}
```

The object itself looks like this:

```
public class Church
{
    //Basic Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }

    ... (some properties)

    //Church Contacts and Services
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public List<Service> Services { get; set; }

    ....

}
```

Notice the last two Properties: Contacts and Services. Each is a 1:Many table within my database. It appears that `Find()` does not return any of this, though. It just sets the two properties to null.

[image: Database Schema, autogenerated by CF Entity Framework]

The actual entries in the database look just how I would expect them to. Each Church has a couple contacts and services associated with them. Yet, it never maps back to the model...

Any thoughts?

**EDIT** Yeah, looks like it wasn't loading those properties until I explicitly told it to. I modified my query by adding this to my ChurchRepository (inherits from GenericRepository)

```
public override Church GetById(object id)
{
    return _db.Include("Contacts").Include("Services").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == (int)id);
}
```

Comment: This was a very helpful link, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764391/entity-framework-find-method-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

You should mark navigation properties as virtual or you could also include them without lazy loading that is best practice.

Try this

```
db.Churces.Include(entity=>entity.Services).
Include(entity=>entity.Contacts).SingleOrDefault(entity=>entity.Id == id)
```

You may have to import `System.Data.Entity` namespace for Include extension method.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working, I can't use the lambdas there and get it to run. However, my solution in the OP seems very similar. (Yes, I added System.Data.Entity,but still no go)

Comment: If you can not see lambda version of Include method after import the namespace so you are totally using lower version than 4.1.

Comment: Checking the version in properties: Runtime version: v4.0.30319, Version: 4.3.1

Comment: Yes, I have a ChurchRepository that holds the context and dbsets that I use and a UnitOfWork class to access a single instance of the context

Comment: OK So you use object browser by right click on entit framework dll and navigate to System.Data.Entity namespace for find Include extension method. There is something wrong on you